How to clear screen in MySQL 9.1 Command Line Client?
I am using MySQL Community Server 9.1.0 Innovation (in windows 10) and trying to clear the screen in MySQL 9.1 Command Line Client using the following command :
system cls;
Similar question already answered at the below links and it tried the solutions provided.

solution 1
solution 2

but NONE WORKS BECAUSE I am getting the following error:
ERROR:
'system' command received, but the --system-command option is off. Skipping.

Is there any way to get rid of this error and successfully execute the command

Sounds like you need to pass --system-command=ON, see "system command, ! command" on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/9.1/en/mysql-commands.html
